# how to check a list of passengers are displayed in drop down options?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a list of all of the passengers stored. The method and the step definition is below;

interactions.cs

```
   public List<string> GetPassengerNames()
    {
        List<string> titleList = new List<string>();
        List<string> forenameList = new List<string>();
        List<string> surnameList = new List<string>();

        var passengerTitles =  _driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.TitleField);
        var passengerForenames =_driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.ForenameField);
        var passengerSurnames = _driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.SurnameField);

        foreach (var passengerTitle in passengerTitles)
        {
            SelectElement passengerTitleSelected = new SelectElement(passengerTitle);
            string passengerTitleText = passengerTitleSelected.SelectedOption.Text;
            titleList.Add(passengerTitleText);

        }
        foreach (var passengerForename in passengerForenames)
        {
            forenameList.Add(passengerForename.GetAttribute("value"));
        }
        foreach (var passengerSurname in passengerSurnames)
        {
            surnameList.Add(passengerSurname.GetAttribute("value"));
        }

        List<string> fullNameList = titleList
            .Zip(forenameList.Zip(surnameList, (firstname, lastname) => firstname + " " + lastname),
                (firstname, lastname) => firstname + " " + lastname).ToList();

        return fullNameList;
    }
```

stepdefinition.cs

```
    [When(@"all passenger details are captured")]
    public void WhenAllPassengerDetailsAreCaptured()
    {
        var passengersList = _passengerDetails.GetPassengerNames();
        ScenarioContext.Current.Add("PassengersList", passengersList);
    }
```

This gives me the following passengers:

```
Mr Test Tester
Mr Testering Tester
```

Now in another specflow step assert that the names from the step above matches with a booking contact drop down options which html is below:

```
<select name="booking-contact" id="booking-contact" class="js-booking-contact-select has-value" data-vv-id="_dv78hd1js" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value="">Choose from list</option> <option value="1">Mr Test Tester</option> <option value="2">Mrs Testering Tester</option> <option value="other">Someone else</option></select>
<option disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value="">Choose from list</option>
<option value="1">Mr Test Tester</option>
<option value="2">Mrs Testering Tester</option>
<option value="other">Someone else</option>
</select>
```

I want to know how to perform the assert which will check that the two passenger names above is displayed in the booking contact drop down as well as the first option 'Choose from list' and someone else.

How can I go about doing this?

The step definition step that needs to perform the assert will go into here:

```
[Then(@"the booking contact drop down displays the correct passengers")]
public void ThenTheBookingContactDropDownDisplaysTheCorrectPassengers()
{

    var passengers = ScenarioContext.Current["PassengersList"].ToString().ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "Choose from list" at start of your full name list like

```
fullNameList.Insert(0, item);
```

Also add "Someone else" at end of list (considering it will be last drop down option)

```
fullNameList.add("Someone else");
```

Now you can validate drop down value as:

```
    IWebElement comboBox = new WebDriverWait(_browserWindow, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(d => _browserWindow.FindElement(By.Id(id)));
                    SelectElement dropdownList = new SelectElement(comboBox);
                    int j = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < fullNameList.Length; i++)
                    {                            
                        if (dropdownList.Options[i].Text == passengersList[j])
                        {
                            j++;
                            Console.WriteLine("Value Matched");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Data not found");
                        }
                    }
```